# How to insert data in postgresql using for loop function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have an array string [1,2,3,4]

Here is my sql

```
INSERT INTO account(account_id, parent_id) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO account(account_id, parent_id) VALUES (2, 10);
INSERT INTO account(account_id, parent_id) VALUES (3, 10);
INSERT INTO account(account_id, parent_id) VALUES (4, 10);
```

how to insert using postgresql forloop function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop:

```
insert into account(account_id, parent_id)
select t.id, 10
from unnest(array[1,2,3,4]) as t(id);
```